# Disable interactivity on page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some trouble with disabling buttons activity in my page.
I am creating a chrome plugin, which can get xpath from selected area, but I need that when I select area, it have to be not interactive.

There is my function code:

```
function highlightDOMElements() {
    var prev;

    document.body.onmouseover = handler;

    function handler(event) {
        if (event.target === document.body || (prev && prev === event.target)) {
            return;
        }

        if (prev) {
            prev.removeEventListener('click', alertXPath);
            prev.classList.toggle(HIGHLIGHT_CLASSNAME);
            prev = undefined;
        }

        if (event.target) {
            prev = event.target;
            prev.classList.toggle(HIGHLIGHT_CLASSNAME);
            prev.addEventListener('click', alertXPath);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use this one:

```
document.addEventListener("click", handler, true);
    function handler(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

but it disabled even my functionality.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("click"...` will handle every click on the entire page. Did you mean to handle the click of a specific button?

Comment: No, I need that every single element on page would be inactive, but I need  to get their xpathes, so i can't make transparent div on my page. But after some time I realised, that I don't need stopPropagation, but I have a problem now, that after i press the button to preventDefault, I couldn't get their functionality back.